# GR breaks down at Planck Mass

Tags: general-relativity, renormalization, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory

I have heard a lot of times (see e.g. papers like [1, 2]) that GR is not renormalizable and breaks down at energies at the scale of the Planck Mass $M_{\text{Planck}}\sim 10^{19}$ GeV. What is the (simple) explanation for these two statements?

1. [On the possibility of laboratory evidence for quantum superposition of geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05842)
2. [General relativity as an effective field theory: The leading quantum corrections](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9405057)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't renormalization with a Planck-scale cutoff work for quantum gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301293/)

Comment: You need to rewrite GR as a perturbative QFT and explicitly show that the coupling is $1/M_P$. You can find more details in my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/467869/133418