# One-loop gravity $\beta$ function

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity

Gravity is renormalizable at one loop, see e.g. [Why is GR renormalizable to one loop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30948/)

What is the one loop gravity $\beta$ function?

Comment: people dont usually bother with writing the one-loop beta function since there is already a non-trivial tree-level part. But the classic ['t Hooft-Veltman paper](https://inspirehep.net/literature/95368) contains all the one-loop counterterms, from which the beta function trivially follows. It is nevertheless indeed annoying that the final result is not easy to find, might be good to write the answer here at some point...